# Unable to move to next page after clicking on button using Selenium Webdriver in IE11

Tags: java, selenium

This is my first post as I am stuck on this problem for many days. My script is unable to move to next page after a click on button. I checked that element is present and then clicked on it. It displays next page but script keeps running and never comes back. It never executes my information message given below.

```
System.out.println("continue button clicked");
```

Copying my Selenium and Java Code. Please help...

HTML:

```
<a tabindex="76" href="javascript:formSubmit()" oncontextmenu="return false">
<img src="/RetailCustomerManagement/resources/graphics/continue_orange_en.gif" style="border:none;"/>
</a>
```

Java Code:(using a frame work)

```
        boolean isElementpresent       = PerformAction.isElementsPresentNameCheck(continuebutton).size()!=0;
        System.out.println("Is Element present? " + isElementpresent);


        PerformAction.waitForElementToBeClickable(continuebutton);
        PerformAction.FuncSubmit(continuebutton);
        //PerformAction.FuncClick(continuebutton);
        System.out.println("continue button clicked");

         }

             catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: this code won't compile as it's missing some part on top (the first closing bracket does not have matching pair). Also we don't know what `PerformAction` is. Please post the code that has enough information.

Comment: Thanks Kiril for your response. I was able to fix the issue by using moveToElement() method and then Click method.

Comment: If you found an answer to your question, please either delete this question or post the answer if you think it would be helpful to others.